# guessing tags depends on content in php

Tags: php, mysql

i need to write a script which guesses tags depends on text content

consider we have this sentence as our story :

> stack overflow internet services,
>   inc; user contributions licensed under
>   cc-wiki with attribution required

now we have some tags in our database table such as

> Internet , License , service

now we need to write a script to guess what tags are good for the above content , it means there is no need to type tags when you write a story , just let the script guess tags

ok here we go with php :

```
$content = " stack overflow internet services, user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required and internet is a good service " ;

$result = $db->sql_query("SELECT tag FROM table_tags");
while ($row= $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
    $tag_title = $row[tag];
    $words = explode(" ", $content ); //break the sentence to words with space 
            for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($words); $i++){
                if ($words[$i] == $tag ) {
                    $outcome .="$words[$i]-";
                }

            }
    }
 echo $outcome ;
```

ok problem :

it repeats tags and outcome would be this :

> internet - internet

Comment: You should try "Select distinct tag ..."

Comment: Take another look at the code, @Nervo Verdezoto. The issue is that 'internet' is repeated twice in the `$content` string - selecting distinct won't change that.

Comment: This approach looks like a classical N²-problem. It could become _very_ inefficient. I cannot think of a better solution at the first glance, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah, you are right... I could not see because of the scroll! in any case some else helped her!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about turning it on its head a little..

Why not **farm more out to the SQL statement itself**? The initial loop to construct the statement will likely have to run fewer times than looping through each returned row if you simply execute an open ended statement, so will thus be faster..

```
    $content = " stack overflow internet services, user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required and internet is a good service " ;

    $words = explode(" ", trim($content) ); //break the sentence to words with space 

    $sql="SELECT `tag` FROM table_tags WHERE ";

                for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($words); $i++){

                   $sql. = " `tag` ='". mysql_real_escape_string($words[$i])."'";

                   if($i!=sizeof($words)-1){
                       $sql.=" OR ";
                   }

                }
     $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

     // returned rows will now ONLY be matching tags

    while ($row= $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
       $tag_title = $row[tag];
    }

    print_r($tag_title);
```

So, if you had a recordset of 1000 rows (tags in your DB), and only 4 potential tags (words in your title), if you loop through the rows in PHP using the proposals above- the loop has to run 1000 times to simply identify 4 possible matches...if you move the criteria/identification to the SQL, the loop only has to run 4 times in order to build the initial filter, which is **far more efficient**. What it will also do is automatically prevent against duplicats - though if they exist in your DB, simply append `'GROUP BY tag'` to `$sql`..

nb. As per the comment below- IN can be used instead of OR:

```
    $sql="SELECT `tag` FROM table_tags WHERE `tag` IN (";

                for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($words); $i++){

                   $sql. = "'". mysql_real_escape_string($words[$i])."'";

                   if($i!=sizeof($words)-1){
                       $sql.=", ";
                   }

                }
     $result = $db->sql_query($sql.")");
```

Comment: your idea is so smart and i really love it , but when i try it the outcome is empty , beside that  your code has some syntax errors , would you mind reviewing it !

Comment: I like this approach but a couple of things to make it better: 1. Make sure tags are indexed. 2. Use IN instead of OR. It's faster. 3. For $deity's sake escape your $words before you put them into a SQL statement! As written its a SQL injection attack vector.

Comment: its somehow odd , it should be working , but cant extract right tags out of content . is it different if we have multi-byte language  like Arabic sentences ?!

Comment: now with the IN  everything is ok but one more thing how to use LIKE statement instead of just equal to ?!

Comment: To use a like statement you'd have to go back to using OR and replace " `tag` ='". mysql_real_escape_string($words[$i])."'"; with " `tag` LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($words[$i])."%'";

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$content = " stack overflow internet services, user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required and internet is a good service " ;

$result = $db->sql_query("SELECT tag FROM table_tags");
while ($row= $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
    $tag_title = $row[tag];
    $words = explode(" ", $content ); //break the sentence to words with space 
            for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($words); $i++){
                if ($words[$i] == $tag ) {
                    //$outcome .="$words[$i]-";
                    $found_tags[$words[$i]] = $words[$i];
                }

            }
    }
 $outcome = implode(' - ', $found_tags);
 echo $outcome ;
```

Comment: hey man  thanks , i tried it and it gave me an error : Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: Is `$found_tags` being populated?

Answer (score 2):

[free terms extractor](http://fivefilters.org/term-extraction/)

Answer (score 1):

Could you add all of your words into an array, but then check whether your individual word exists in the array before adding it?

```
if ($words[$i] == $tag ) 
{
  if (!in_array($outcome, $words[$i]))
  {
    $outcome[] = $words[$i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the words in an array first then just loop through your tags. This will prevent duplicates and speed your process up significantly:

```
$words = explode(" ", $content);

while ($row= $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
     $tag_title = $row[tag];
     if( in_array( $tag_title, $words ) ) {
          $found_tags[] = $tag_title;
     }
}
```

Note you don't need an index. Using `[]` will cause PHP to use the next index for your array.

Comment: I like this approach more than my one.